# Had Noah a wicked wife, son?

Tags: talmud-gemara, midrash, mabul, noach-noah-the-man

**Is there any instance in Jewish literature that mentions that one of Noah's sons was a disbeliever who refused to come aboard the Ark, instead preferring to climb a mountain, where he drowned?
or depicts Noah's wife as an evil woman who was false to her husband or a disbeliever ?**

The Quran states that Noah's wife was not a believer with him so she did not join him; neither did one of Noah's sons , who was secretly a disbeliever but had pretended faith in front of Noah. The sons of Noah are not expressly mentioned in the Qur'an, except for the fact that one of the sons was among the people who did not follow his own father, not among the believers and thus was washed away in the flood :

Quran 11:43 And ˹so˺ the Ark sailed with them through waves like mountains. Noah called out to his son, who stood apart, “O my dear son! Come aboard with us and do not be with the disbelievers.”
He replied, “I will take refuge on a mountain, which will protect me from the water.” Noah cried, “Today no one is protected from Allah’s decree except those to whom He shows mercy!” And the waves came between them, and his son was among the drowned.

Noah's wife is referred to in the Qur'an as an evil woman.
Allah sets forth, for an example to the Unbelievers, the wife of Noah and the wife of Lut: they were (respectively) under two of our righteous servants, but they were false to their (husbands), and they profited nothing before Allah on their account, but were told: "Enter ye the Fire along with (others) that enter!

— [Qur'an 66:10](https://quran.com/66/10?translations=131)

God sets forth, for an example to the Unbelievers, the wife of Noah and the wife of Lut: they were (respectively) under two of our righteous servants, but they were false to their (husbands), and they profited nothing before God on their account, but were told: "Enter ye the Fire along with (others) that enter!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question! Do you have any reason to believe that such a son and wife would be mentioned in Jewish literature? Are you aware of other cultures who do have such stories, and you wish to compare then to Judaism?

Comment: Hi  Binyomin ,I'm not sure if such son and wife are mentioned in Jewish literature, that way.  but as I believe that the prophet of Muslims borrowed lots of his Quranic stories from the Jewish literature ,so I would like to check which  Jewish source (if any), did he copy from .

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that in the Quran there is such a story told and you want to see if it has a source in jewish literature. Perhaps you could edit your question to mention this point, as well as a link to where in the Quran such a story appears?

Comment: Close voters: the question is on topic. The fact that it was motivated by something outside Judaism is NOT what the comparative religion close reason is for. Even without the motivation being stated the question is equally intelligible and answerable.

Answer (score 3):

No. The Torah is very clear that Noah's wife joined him in the Ark. Not much else is known about her. The Torah lists three sons of Noah -Shem, Cham, and Yefes- and makes clear that all three entered the Ark and repopulated the world after the flood. The son Cham is listed as having sinned after the flood, and according to Rabbinic sources also violated G-d's commandment for the people on the Ark to be celibate, but he was on the Ark.

In general, many stories in the Quran are loosely based on the Torah, but with many significant details changed.

Comment: It's quite plausible he had many more children who didn't join him and were thus never mentioned. I'd say it's quite likely in fact. 600 years of life and only 3 children? Anyway, this isn't a great answer, completely ignoring the existence of Midrash. How do you know there aren't any midrashim along these lines?

Comment: thanx N.T &  Double AA..I think I found the source where Muhammad copied his idea about Noah's wife !!  https://jwa.org/encyclopedia/article/naamah-midrash-and-aggadah  still can't find anything about his son..

Comment: The article leaves out a crucial point: according to the opinion she was wicked, she was not Noah's wife. A wicked woman would not have deserved to be saved on the ark. Maybe Muhammad missed this point in the Quran.

Comment: @DoubleAA Rashi specifically addresses this point. He says that Hashem delayed Noah's children to prevent the chance that they would be wicked *and not deserve to be saved*. Under the age of 100 though, they were not at the age of punishment yet in dinei shamayim in those generations.

Comment: @N.T. Rashi is not the only relevant piece of Jewish literature...

Comment: @N.T. In Genesis Rabba it does indicate she wasn't his wife, but in the Midrash Hagadol there is no such indication https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51452&st=&pgnum=164 Please don't get distracted trying to disprove Mohammed or something. This is just a question and you should answer it normally.

Comment: @DoubleAA Do you really think that a wicked woman was saved on the teivah (or even married to Noach?) On the contrary, the Midrashim you quote don't say anything about her being Noach's wife, so why would you assume they agree with the Midrash that says she was? The Midrash Rabbah that brings the opinion she was his wife is also clear that the opinion she was wicked disagrees.

Comment: sorry I don't get the point, can we say that  the midrash calls her his wife, but has 2 opinions about her ,one of them is that she was wicked?

Comment: The Midrash that says she was his wife is clear that the opinion she was wicked disagrees. Presumably the other Midrash that says she was wicked also says she was not his wife. Especially because it does not seem sensible that a wicked woman was saved on the Ark.

Comment: @caprireds One midrash cites two opinions: Naamah is noah's wife and is righteous or she is not his wife and is evil. Another midrash cites opinions that Naamah is not righteous without mentioning if she was noah's wife. Those are the dry facts without the editorializing. Another fact is the random internet user N.T. finds the notion that an evil person would be saved on the ark untenable despite admitting to Cham's presence thereon; I'm not sure if you find that last fact helpful.

Comment: Rashi clearly says a wicked person would not be saved. It seems whatever Cham did was after he was on the Ark already.

Answer (score 3):

The Torah says that Noach, his wife, his three sons, and their wives entered the ark: Genesis 7:13

“In the selfsame day entered Noah, and Shem, and Ham, and Japheth, the sons of Noah, and Noah’s wife, and the three wives of his sons with them, into the ark.”

As far as who was evil and who was not, Genesis 7:1 only states: “And the LORD said unto Noah, Come thou and all thy house into the ark; for thee have I seen righteous before me in this generation.”

As far as other sources whose authors believe in the Torah, we can look at the the book of Jubilee In the case of Noah's wife, in Jubilees her name is given as Emzara, his cousin (Jub. 4:33). It states nothing about her character. According to one midrash, Naamah was the wife of Noah. Another interpretation has her as the wife of one of his sons. Genesis Rabbah 23:3 identifies Naamah, the daughter of Lemech and sister
of Tubal-cain (Gen. 4:22), as Noah's wife.  Another doesn’t state whose wife she is. As of her character? According to the Rabbis, Naamah was Noah’s wife; as her name indicates, her actions were pleasing (ne’imim—Gen. Rabbah 23:3). According to another view, however, she acted improperly, for she beat on a drum and drew people to engage in idolatry, and her musical activity increased corruption among people. This tradition is apparently connected with a different interpretation of the name Naamah, from ne’imah (melody and song) (Targum Pseudo-Jonathan on Gen. 4:22).  There does not seem to be singularity on whether Naamah was Noach’s wife, one of his son’s wives, or simply mother of the neflim and temptress of the fallen angels. In the instance of her being Noach’s wife (or that of one of his sons), there are portrayals of her being both wholesome and evil.

Sefer haYashar and Genesis Rabba both agree that Noah's wife was called Naamah. According to the latter, she was the sister of Tubal-cain (Genesis 4:21); according to the former, she was a daughter of Enoch, and Noah married her when he was 498 years old. The 17th-century theologian John Gill mentioned a theory which identified Naamah instead with the name of the wife of Ham, son of Noah, who he believed may have become confused with Noah's wife.